# php error in mysql execution

Tags: php, html

Ok I have this code:

```
//this is the hi.php//
<?php
//highlight items//
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hi WHERE pp='2'");

$hi = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //<--- this is the line 13//
  {
  $hi .= "<div id='hicontainer'><a id='download_now' class='imgx' href='#?w=700' rel='popup'><img src='".$row['name']."' />";
  $hi .= "<p>".$row['title']."</p>";
  $hi .= "<a href='#?w=700' id='".$row['id']."' rel='popup' class='imgx'>View full</a>    </div>";
  }

//Lots of lots of code here I just specified those code which in error.//

mysql_close($con);
```

?>

and heres where im going to display the output actually.

```
<td>
<!--highlight items-->
<div id="tbtitle">
<img src="Images/galleryicon.png"/><p>Highlight items</p>
</div>
<div id="tblgal">
<? echo $hi; ?>
</div>
</td>
```

But i get an error saying: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\madeinusa\hi.php on line 13."

please, im stuck with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tip: **always do a search for the exact error message.** You'll find tons of results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given

Comment: Also, `echo mysql_error()` can help solve most issues. Do so beneath your `mysql_query(...)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably have an error in your query `"SELECT * FROM hi WHERE pp='2'"` 
Try executing that query directly in mysql and see what happens. Make sure you have the table names and columns spelt right.

Also, try quoting the table names and columns in backtick ` characters to avoid accidentally using MySQL reserved words.

Comment: He should always throw an exception or a generic error message to the browser

Answer (score 1):

`$result` has a boolean value - probably because your query failed.

You should validate the result, before trying to use it.

After your query, you could do something like the following to see why your query fails:

```
if(!$result)
  exit(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

or, more simply, you can use

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hi WHERE pp='2'") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

check to this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```

Comment: if connection was not established, it would already exit the code with the error "'Could not connect: "....

Answer (score 0):

First you should use proper exception handling in the code.  After the line

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hi WHERE pp='2'");
```

you should check whether it returns resource id or any error in the way

```
if(!$result){
    // if you use try-catch, then use
   throw new Exception(mysql_error());
   // Or you can use
   die(mysql_error());
}else{
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //<--- this is the line 13//
     {
        $hi .= "<div id='hicontainer'><a id='download_now' class='imgx' href='#?w=700'     rel='popup'><img src='".$row['name']."' />";
        $hi .= "<p>".$row['title']."</p>";
        $hi .= "<a href='#?w=700' id='".$row['id']."' rel='popup' class='imgx'>View    full</a>    </div>";
     }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

"SELECT * FROM hi WHERE pp='2'" query may return false means there are no records that full fill query.Try echo mysql_num_rows($result); in order to know no of rows return for query.

Comment: If there are no results, `mysql_query` will return an *empty resultset*, not `false`.

Comment: but value of variable will be false as there is empty resultset in query

Comment: No, an empty resultset is a mysql resource type. It is *not* a boolean `false`. `mysql_query` only returns a boolean `false` if something was wrong with the query and it could not be executed.